# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated function not dismissing the view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to use `dismissModalViewController:Animated:` to dismiss my view, but it is not dismissing it, no matter what I try. You can see my attempts to release the view in the `hideSplash` method at the bottom. Please, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. My code posted below:

```
#import "SplashViewController.h"

@implementation SplashViewController

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload {

}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) showSplash {
    modalViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    modalViewController.view = modelView;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating ];
    //[self bigcalculation];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"View Did Appear");
    [self bigcalculation];
}

- (void) bigcalculation {
    NSLog(@"Big Calc Start");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 648230; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1200; j++) {

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Big Calc End");
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) hideSplash {
    NSLog(@"Hide");
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    //[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"End Hide");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in case anyone else has this issue the line

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil];
```

Should be

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: You can replace it with   `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideSplash)
                         withObject:NULL
                      waitUntilDone:NO];` It is because you need a separate thread for updating the UI.

Answer (score 9):

The modal view controller is not responsible for dismissal. That burden is placed on the view controller that called the modalViewController.

Try replacing:

```
[[self modalviewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

with

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Look at my code i have tried that already that is why is is commented out.

Comment: You can call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on the modal view controller and it will be forwarded to the parent. This can also be used to dismiss a "stack" of modal view controllers that were presented in succession (as described in the documentation).

Comment: Actually Mark, the controller we're dismissing should be the receiver. It may be called by the presenting view controller, but the receiver of the method should be the one dismissing.

Comment: This is true as of iOS 5. In prior versions of the frameworks, the parent view controller was responsible for dismissal. The concept of a parent view controller has now changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```